# using jquery draggable can you create a helper based on the dragged item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wish to create a custom helper based on the element being dragged. I'm dragging documents and I'd like the document's number to be part of the custom helper.

I know how to create a helper during init like this:

```
helper: function()
        {
            return $("<div class='fax16'></div>");
        }
```

But what I really want to do is maybe in response to the start event get access to the element being dragged and use some of its properties to set the helper.

Something like:

```
start: function(event, ui)
{
   var docID = //somehow access the dragged element
   ui.helper = $("<div class='save16'>" + docID + "</div>");  //Set drag Helper    
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the problem is to use the mousedown and mouseup events on your dragged elements to set a class "over" on the element whenever the mouse is on top of it. Then the helper can look for the element with class "over" and access it.

```
$('li').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).addClass("over");
});

$('li').mouseup(function() {
    $('li').removeClass("over");
});

helper: function() {                                    
    $(".over") //the element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure but a have a feeling this is what you need.

```
start: function(event, ui)
{
   var docID = ui.find('.fax16'); //somehow access the dragged element
   //ui.helper = $("<div class='save16'>" + docID + "</div>");  //Set drag Helper    

}
```